# Importing multiple images from Dropbox with Feeds

Tags: commerce, feeds

As part of a product import, I am trying to import images from a link contained in a column of an Excel file.  Each link points to a Dropbox folder with 2 image sub-folders (named PRINT and WEB).  Is it possible to import multiple image files from a Dropbox folder using Feeds?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can read the images's urls inside the Excel table – or actually let your D7 install read them? Once you have that and can actually also access the files on dropbox, it should be possible to load them into your D7 install.

I had a similar, though probably more trivial problem. I had the images' urls and all related info nicely wrapped in a simgle xml file. Looking for a way to actually import the images I came across the Media Feeds module which basically let's you 'import' media files into as an image or file field into an entity (e.g. a node).

The module's project page (https://www.drupal.org/project/media_feeds) has also a link to a screencast – should not be too complicated once you can read the Excel table / get access to the images' urls.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to place the images in a folder under your Dropbox Public folder. This folder allows files to be retrieved via a non-changing URL rather than the unique URL that Dropbox uses when you want to share an individual file.  This functionality was removed from the free version of Dropbox on October 4, 2012 but is still available for legacy accounts or paid accounts.

You can then include the filename (and use feeds tamper to create a full URL) or include the full URLs in your import file.  You must use the public dropbox folder to be able to compute these URLs otherwise it won't work.

Look for "Copy Public Link" not "Share Link" to get the URL from dropbox.com. When looking at a "Public Link" you'll see the full folder structure and filename in the URL, with a Share Link you will not see this.